# Porblem using chartjs with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts

I'm trying to render a chart in my view with data from my database. The problem that I'm getting is:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/yamazummi/chart 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

It's the firt time that I'm using ChartJs with Laravel. I have no idea where I might have gone wrong.

Here's all the code that I add:

Controller:

```
public function chart(){
    $data = DB::table('bandelete')
                ->join('posto', 'posto.id', '=', 'bandelete.posto_id')
                ->join('silhueta', 'silhueta.id', '=', 'bandelete.silhueta_id')
                ->select('posto.cod as pcod', 'silhueta.name as sname', DB::raw('SUM(va + nva) as tempo'))
                ->where('posto_id', '=', 1)
                ->get();

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

View:
The chartjs script:

```
var url = "{{url('yamazummi/chart')}}";
    var silhuetas = new Array();
    var tempo = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get(url, function(response){
            response.forEach(function(data){
                silhuetas.push(data.sname);
                tempo.push(tempo);
            });
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type:'bar',
                    data:{
                        labels:silhuetas,
                        datasets:[{
                            label:'Tempo',
                            data:tempo,
                            borderWidth:1
                        }]
                    },
                    options:{
                        scales: {
                            yAxes:[{
                                ticks:{
                                    beginAtZero:true
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
    });
```

Were I render:

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="280" width="600"></canvas>
```

My route:

```
Route::get('yamazummi/chart', 'BandeleteController@chart');
```

The script linked to my app:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**Edit:**

When I open the route I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (42000)

Comment: This is not the chart.js error. Most likely you did a mistake in the controller. Set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file and provide with more error details.

Comment: Ignore chartjs for now; you've created a basic GET endpoint for the data so you should be able to type the url into the browser's address bar to make sure the server sends back the JSON reply properly.

Comment: @ChrisG I add the error that I get accessing the route